# How can i solve this issue of dependencies in flutter android studio?

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, dependencies, pubspec

Im new to flutter. please advise how can i solve this issue? I tried to update all dependencies but i got error

This is the error i get when running `flutter pub add flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle`

`Because tflite_flutter_helper >=0.3.1 depends on camera ^0.9.4+5 which depends on flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^2.0.2, tflite_flutter_helper >=0.3.1 requires f lutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^2.0.2. And because image_picker >=0.6.3 <0.7.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^1.0.2, tflite_flutter_helper >=0.3.1 is incompatible with image_pic ker >=0.6.3 <0.7.0-nullsafety. So, because yyyy depends on both image_picker ^0.6.7+22 and tflite_flutter_helper ^0.3.1, version solving failed. pub finished with exit code 65`

**my pubspec.yaml file**

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  tflite_flutter: ^0.9.0
  tflite_flutter_helper: ^0.3.1
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+14
```

EDIT:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql1p5.png

Comment: You need to update other dependencies to latest one as well

Comment: flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Answer (score 1):

The issues is probably as a result of having multiples of same dependencies with conflicting versions across various packages.

Checkout this official flutter documentation on dependency versioning and resolution. [Here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#package-versions)

You may need to share your `pubspec.yaml` for more details, but you would want to try using an older version of `tflite_flutter_helper`

Comment: shared the pubspec.yaml